# Problema usando un objeto en un React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy tratando de hacer una aplicación pegajosa, y para eso programé dos componentes. Uno es el contenedor, que renderiza cada Sticky Note dentro de él, y el segundo utiliza los datos que se le dan desde un JSON.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    notes: tasks
  }

  render(){
    return <Stickycontainer tasks={this.state.notes}/>
  }
}

class Stickycontainer extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return this.props.tasks.map(e => <Stickynote data={e}/>)
  }
}
```

Este fragmento funciona bien, porque intenté en lugar de representar un Stickynote, simplemente renderizar un elemento de párrafo con cada objeto y sus propiedades de la matriz. Pero el error viene cuando intento implementar el componente Sticky a continuación:

```
class Stickynote extends React.Component{
    state = {
      show: true
    }

    render(){
      if(this.state.show){
        return(
          <div className="StickyNotes">
            <p>{this.props.data.id} - {this.props.data.description} - {this.props.data.title}</p>
    
            <div className="Actions">
              <button className="Delete" onClick={() => this.setState({show: false})}>
                  <Icon>delete</Icon>
              </button>
    
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      } else {
        return null;
      }
        
    } 
  }
```

Me da este error, el cual no le veo ninguna lógica porque compila sin dar ni un solo warning o error:

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in
> components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
> object.
>
> Check the render method of App

¿Qué hago?

Comment: Te recomiendo que coloques un debugger en el componente que te está dando error ya que al parecer la data que le estás pasando no es correcta, verifica con un debugger y seguro lo soluciona

Comment: ¿Estas seguro de que `this.props.tasks` es un `array de objetos`? saludos

Comment: @g.4 Hola, sí. Viene del estado de App, que tiene el contenido de un JSON que contiene un array de objetos.

Comment: @CristianMendoza qué debugger puedo usar para esta situación, al menos en VS Code? Realmente no he usado uno para React o JavaScript en general, me puse a intentar trastear con uno y realmente no pude sacar ni entender nada de lo que estaba haciendo.

Comment: [Pregunta relacionada](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130539/uncaught-error-invariant-violation-element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string)